# DDR2 memory compatibility

Tags: memory, ddr

I'm planing to change memory on my old computer. I found 2 modules of [this](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KHX6400D2LLK2_2GN.pdf) and 2 modules of [this](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KHX6400D2K2_2G.pdf) memory. Will they work together? Motherboard is Asus Striker II Formula.

Comment: Just purchase memory that is the same frequency and voltage as the modules you have currently.DDR2.  The modules your asking about are nearly identical.

Answer (score -1):

The users manual says this:
Non-ECC DDR2 1066/800/667/533MHz Memory Modules up to 8GB max.
Don't buy any memory larger than 2GB per module; but, almost any desktop memory ought to work fine.

Comment: "Don't buy any memory larger than 2GB per module" - The user manual says 8GB modules work?  This statement does not compute.

Comment: From page 2-18: "You may install a maximum of 2 GB DIMMs on each slot"